# How to change the font and color of QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a QString like this `">>> This is an Arrow."` , now I want to have `>>>` in bold and red, How to do that ?

i have looked over some pages and found this syntax

```
QString redPart = QString("<span style=" color:#ff0000;">%1</span>").arg(">>>");
```

but it gives some error like ")" missing and, I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Your problem is the second " ends the string literal.

Comment: See "[How to Set custom text Color in QTextEdit?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5757540/90527)", "[QTextEdit with different text colors (Qt / C++)](//stackoverflow.com/q/2857864/90527)", "[How to change a color of QString item in QListView](//stackoverflow.com/q/34685635/90527)", …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your error message means that you are missing a ) because you have to escape the quotes when using them in a string literal (**\"** instead of **"**) i.e. do something like

```
QString redPart = QString("<span style=\" color:#ff0000;\">%1</span>").arg(">>>");
```

on the other hand, **Qstring** is a class that has nothing to do with widgets or guis at all, so properties like color, bold format etc arent defined there, so you need to use a widget or something that you can display to the user then if widget: you can set the stylesheet, if a QLabel: you can set the text using richtext.

Answer (score 3):

QString is not a visual component, and therefore does not have a font or color property. It's just a data structure that holds text. If you want to display that text, you can use one of the many visual objects like a QLabel.

The compiler error you're getting is probably because your use of quotation marks is incorrect. Try it like this instead:

```
QString redPart = QString("<span style='color:#ff0000;'>%1</span>").arg(">>>");
```

Comment: Thanks, now what if i use this QString redPart in the item of QListWIdget, will it be coloured in red ??

Comment: The QListWidgetItem should be able to handle rich text. Even if it can't, a QListWidgetItem supports setting a foreground color.

Comment: actually it was not able to, i used this `QString redPart = QString("<span style=\" color:#ff0000;\">%1</span>").arg(">>>"); `  and when i tried to print it in a textedit, it was working, i got `>>>` in red color,  However when i tried to print it in a item
it came in as `span style= " color:#ff0000;">>></span>` as text.